# Именованные параметры в запросах

Tags: java, jdbc

Есть ли какой нибудь способ/фреймворк в Java обращаться к параметрам запроса по имени, а не по индексу?

```
stmt = con.prepare("SELECT field1 FROM mytable WHERE myfield2 = :param1");
stmt.setIntPrm("param1", 2);
```

Comment: В жпа так можно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чистый JDBC именованные параметры не поддерживает, только индексированные. Другое дело, что есть различные инструменты, которые позволяют обойти это ограничение. К примеру Spring-jdbc (см [NamedParameterJdbcTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html)), JPA и т.д.